# There are no solutions for $x'=\frac{x}{t}$ such that $x(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This exercise is from the book Differential equations by Hirsch and

I really don't understand the purpose of the exercise.

> Consider the first order equation $x'=\frac{x}{t}.$ What can be said about solutions that satisfy $x(0)=0$ and $x(0)=a\neq 0$?

I solved the system, making the assumption that $t\neq 0,$ it is  $x(t)=ct$ for some constant $c$.

So I can't even consider the initial value $x(0)=0$ or $x(0)=a\neq 0$ due the first assumption I did when solving the equation.

The answer for the exercise should be:

There are no solutions such that satisfy $x(0)=0$ or $x(0)=a\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Indeed I find the statement of the exercise most confusing. What one **should** say about a differential equation $$x'(t)=f(x(t),t)$$ is that no solution $x(t)$ can be defined at times $t$ such that $f(z,t)$ exists for no value of $z$. And this is exactly what happens here with $t=0$, whether $z=0$ or $z=a\ne0$, since the function $f:(u,t)\to u/t$ is defined on the set $\mathbb R\times(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: @Did I see. Yes the statement is confusing, you can check it in the book (Chapter 7, page 156)